# Display difference between Chrome and FireFox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RussAbbott/XQbjk/26/) Chrome and Firefox display the expanding tree significantly differently. This causes a problem in Chrome. When one expands the tree by moving the cursor down the right side of a visible node, the node that one is moving to jumps to the left. Depending on where the cursor is, it's possible to lose the entire tree, forcing one to start at the top again. Firefox simply expands to the right, and this problem doesn't occur.

Any idea how to get Chrome to display like Firefox?

Thanks.

P.S. IE is like Firefox. Chrome is the odd man out.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but changing "ul:hover > li > ul" to display:block instead of display:inline will at least get them to display consistently across browsers.

Comment: is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/XQbjk/27/

Comment: Here's a [version] [1] that uses opacity instead of display, which makes the effect clearer. [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/RussAbbott/6YhMg/1/

Comment: Very interesting, Rob. The only difference that I can see is that you changed text-align from center to right!

Comment: Hi Russ, it's because you are centering the text in ul. So maybe [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/XQbjk/30/) is ok? Btw, you should accept some of the answers people wrote to you on your previous questions, you are on 0% and that seems not very good. Have good time.